# Converting a matrix to upper-triangular form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to convert the following Jacobian matrix to upper-triangular in order to find its eigenvalues:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-u-k_{12} & k_{21} & 0 \\
k_{12} & -k_{21}-k_{23}-s & k_{32} \\
0 & k_{23} & -k_{32}
\end{bmatrix}$$

I began by using Gaussian elimination, but quickly realised I couldn't fully change the necessary entries to $0$. Here is where I got to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-u-k_{12} & k_{21} & 0 \\
-u & -k_{23}-s & k_{32} \\
-u & -s & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not sure if there's a method or forgetting or where to go forwards from either of these points. Any advice?

Comment: This is possible to do but the formula is rather nasty. If you only care about the eigenvalues, it would be much more efficient to simply compute $\det(A-\lambda I)$. (The formula will still be nasty, of course, but the chance for error is probably lower.)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky I tried doing that method to begin with but realised my question specifically asked for the upper-triangular method.